# FFMPEG - encode and decode 8bit PNG images

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a few png images (8bit) which I want to pack into a mkv file with libx264 encoding and the `pix_fmt` flag set to gray. When I extract the individual frames they are bloated to 24 bit. Any idea how to fix that?

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmt gray -framerate 1 -r 30 -i C:\%d.png \
       -vcodec libx264 -crf 0 C:\test.mkv

ffmpeg -i C:\test.mkv -r 30 C:\%d.png
```

Comment: When you say your PNG images are 8-bit, do you mean they are greyscale? Or do you mean they are palette images?

Answer (score 2):

`-pix_fmt` option needs to be an output option not input to make the output format to be grayscale. Try

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -r 30 -i C:\%d.png \
       -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt gray -crf 0 C:\test.mkv
```

Comment: That's one part of the puzzle... adding -pix_fmt to the output image. Doesn't seem to do anything on the mkv creation
ffmpeg  -i C:\test.mkv -pix_fmt gray C:\%d.png
does the trick. Thank you for sure for the hint. I was oblivious to the fact that order of the parameters matter

Answer (score 2):

If you do this, you can find out what the PNG encoder in `ffmpeg` is capable of and what controls it can understand:

```
ffmpeg -v warning -h encoder=png
```

**Sample Output**

```
Encoder png [PNG (Portable Network Graphics) image]:
    General capabilities: threads 
    Threading capabilities: frame
    Supported pixel formats: rgb24 rgba rgb48be rgba64be pal8 gray ya8 gray16be ya16be monob
(A)PNG encoder AVOptions:
  -dpi               <int>        E..V....... Set image resolution (in dots per inch) (from 0 to 65536) (default 0)
  -dpm               <int>        E..V....... Set image resolution (in dots per meter) (from 0 to 65536) (default 0)
  -pred              <int>        E..V....... Prediction method (from 0 to 5) (default none)
     none            0            E..V.......
     sub             1            E..V.......
     up              2            E..V.......
     avg             3            E..V.......
     paeth           4            E..V.......
     mixed           5            E..V.......
```

I assume you want to get an 8-bit palette image, as opposed to an 8-bit gray image, so you need to look at the line with *"Supported pixel formats"*:

```
Supported pixel formats: rgb24 rgba rgb48be rgba64be pal8 gray ya8 gray16be ya16be monob
```

So, I think you need to add `-pix_fmt pal8` before your output filename. If you meant 8-bit greyscale, use `-pix_fmt gray`